# Multiple substitute commands when matching some lines in sed

Tags: regex, perl, vim, sed

With Vim's global command, it is possible to chain multiple commands with `|` (pipe) symbol when matching some lines, for example:

```
g/match/ s/11/00/ | s/22/11/g
```

Is this also possible with sed without repeating the `match` regex?

```
sed -e '/match/ s/11/00/ ; /match/ s/22/11/g ' $file
```

If not, is it possible to do this with perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
echo "->11,22<-
->01,20<-" | sed '/11/ {s/11/00/g; s/22/11/g}'
```

Output is:

```
->00,11<-
->01,20<-
```

- the `/11/` restricts the `s` commands inside its `{ ... }` block only to  matching lines

Comment: FYI in awk you wouldn't need to duplicate the `/11/`: `awk 'gsub(/11/,"00"){gsub(/22/,"11")}1'`.